# Evernote API - Getting notes from Publicly shared notebook - in Android app

Tags: java, android, share, public, evernote

I am developing an Android app to manipulate Evernote notes. In one of the use cases, I need to access the notes from publicly shared notebook from other user.

I tried getting getPublicUserInfo.

```
PublicUserInfo pubInfo = null;

pubInfo = mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createUserStoreClient().getClient().getPublicUserInfo("user name");

mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createNoteStoreClient().getPublicNotebook(.......)
```

But first method is always throwing Exception (TException).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK folks I got the solution for getting public notes.

1st Step: Get userid and uri of the public notebook

How to get user id and uri -->
First of, try to get the url of the public note.. Lets take an example

https://www.evernote.com/pub/evertemplate138/evertemplate

In above url, "evertemplate138" is the user id and "evertemplate" is the uri.

2nd Step: Create Linked notebook instance for the public notebook
You can create using the method createLinkedNotebook

3rd Step: Get syncchunk data using method - getLinkedNotebookSyncChunk

4th Step: Get shared notes using syncchunk data

Code snippet:

```
inkedNotebook linkedNotebook1 = new LinkedNotebook();
linkedNotebook1.setShareName("<Name of notebook>");
linkedNotebook1.setUsername("evernote user id");
linkedNotebook1.setUri("uri of the public notebook");
notestore.createLinkedNotebook(linkedNotebook1, new OnClientCallback<LinkedNotebook>()  
{ 
   public void onSuccess(LinkedNotebook data) {
       notestore.getLinkedNotebookSyncChunk(data, 0, 100, true, new OnClientCallback<SyncChunk>() { 

        public void onSuccess(SyncChunk Syncdata) {
           SharedNotes = data.getNotes();
           }
        }

  }
 } );
```

Comment: I am getting notestore.createLinkedNotebook here.